# failure writing sector .. to hd0

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

[image]

I have a dual boot windows 10 - linux system and just installed ubuntu 18.04 a couple days ago. The error in the picture below just started showing up.

It doesnt prevent me from using ubuntu or windows, just curious what's causing it.

I googled around a bit - ended up running bad blocks, gnome disks, crystal disk info and chkdsk in windows .. nothing so far points to the drive failing. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does sound like a hdd/sdd issue to me, so I'd ask your hdd/sdd electronics to provide info about it's health (ie. view your SMART or self-monitoring analysis & reporting technology which is on almost all drives (excluding a few low-end drives)).  You can view the data with `smartctl` or `gnome-disks` (gnome-disks is a gui tool & provides far less data so is easier to understand).   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools for more info

Comment: I added a picture above. I used gnome-disks again and that was the result. I will give smartmontools a try and report back later today or tomorrow

Comment: I followed help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools. It found no errors. Added picture to original post

Comment: You might be effected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1553687

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. I'll keep an eye out for a solution but it doesn't seem to effect my system negatively so I'm going to just leave it alone

Answer (score 1):

### Now this seems like an old question by now, but since alot of people around the internet seems to have this problem, I'd like to post how I fixed the problem.

**I had two problems:**

1. can't find command "hwmatch"
2. failure writing sector 0x... to "hd0"

**The first error I fixed by running:**

1. sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64
2. sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64
   Through the whole reconfigure process, I just pressed "enter"

The second error, the same as yours, I fixed by changing the boot mode in BIOS from "UEFI" to "legacy mode"

Comment: where you run those commands?

Answer (score -2):

try upgrading to an SSD or SSHD. hard disks does'nt work well for laptops (SSHD's also, but it's better than hard disks) . if you are on a desktop, try a new hard disk or SSD.

Comment: I have the same error using a laptop with an SSD. Sorry, but simply stating that "hard disks does'nt work well for laptops" is just plain non-sense. Also you don't say why.